# Why doesn't the job list mark the jobs that I already applied for?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

It already has the flag for "expressed interest" but not for "applied for", why?

Comment: @Des Is anyone working on it? It's been escalated many times

Comment: @student Could you point me to a previous report please? This looks like an easy fix but I want to make sure I'm fixing the right thing

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Not sure but I could still see [already applied jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm9hN.png)

Comment: @student this question is about the list of jobs. I can see applied jobs inside their descriptions, too.

Comment: @user626528 Can you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the bug report!

The code was logically correct but the text had been erroneously copy-and-pasted. Here's the fix:

[image]

Comment: The jobs I applied for aren't marked in the job list, in any way.

Comment: @user626528 It should look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/ZqJnlwX). Note that on the Jobs home page, jobs that you've applied to are filtered out by default. You may need to search directly for the job to which you applied in order to see it in the list

Comment: Apparently, the problem is that for many ads "Apply" redirects to an external website, and SE doesn't track that.